# Using infinite scroll plugin on wordpress without "next navigation" functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've developed [this page](http://www.onecia.com.br/oneoff). There is many offers to load on main page, so i'm trying to make a "infinite scroll" function. To develop the page, i first made it on a bootstrap template, and after i turned into a page model template, on my real estate theme.

The problem is: All the "infinite scroll plugins" i've downloaded request 4 fields: Navigation selector, Next selector, Item selector and Content selector, as you can see [here](http://prntscr.com/hk1fxk). The problem is that i only can provide two of this four fields: Item selector `#seletor` and content selector (.portfolio.items2). Here is the code that loops all the info:

```html
 
<div id="seletor">
    <div class="portfolio-items2">
    <?php $newsArgs = 
          array( 
             'post_type' => 'property',
             'posts_per_page' => 200,
             "orderby" => 'meta_value_num',
             "meta_key" => 'numerooff',
             "order" => 'DESC',
             'tax_query' => array(
                array( 
                      'taxonomy' => 'property-status',
                      'field'    => 'slug',
                      'terms'    => 'oneoff')));                   
            $newsLoop = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );                  
            while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="col-md-4 shortcode-col listing_wrapper <?php meta('seletoroff');?>" > 
            <div class="property_listing" data-link="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>">
                <div class="listing-unit-img-wrapper">
                    <div class="property_media"></div>
                    <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>">
                        <img width="525" height="350" src="<?php meta('imagemoff');?>" class="lazyload img-responsive wp-post-image" alt=""  sizes="(max-width: 525px) 100vw, 525px" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="tag-wrapper">
                        <div class="featured_div"><?php meta('porcentooff');?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h4>
                    <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>">
                        <?php meta('titulooff');?>
                    </a>
                </h4> 
                
                <div class="property_location_image">
                    <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>" rel="tag">
                        <span style="font-size: 15px;"><?php meta('bairrooff');?></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <br>

               <div class="property_listing_details">
               <?php $post_meta_data = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                if( !empty($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_size'][0]) ) {
                    $prop_size = $post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_size'][0];
                    echo '<div class="inforoom">'. $prop_size .'m² <div class="info_labels"><img src="http://www.onecia.com.br/wp-content/themes/site2016/images/icon-size.png" style="max-width: 14%; height: auto;"></div></div>';
            }

            if( !empty($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms'][0]) ) {
                    $prop_bedrooms = floatval($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms'][0]);
                    $bedrooms_label = ($prop_bedrooms > 1)? __('Bedrooms','framework' ): __('Bedroom','framework');
                    echo '<div class="infobath">'. $prop_bedrooms .'<div class="info_labels"><img src="http://www.onecia.com.br/wp-content/themes/site2016/images/icon-bed.png" style="max-width: 17%; height: auto;"></div></div>';
             }

            if( !empty($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms'][0]) ) {
                    $prop_bathrooms = floatval($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms'][0]);
                    $bathrooms_label = ($prop_bathrooms > 1)?__('Bathrooms','framework' ): __('Bathroom','framework');
                    echo '<div class="infosize">'. $prop_bathrooms .'<div class="info_labels"><img src="http://www.onecia.com.br/wp-content/themes/site2016/images/icon-bath.png" style="max-width: 17%; height: auto;">
                    </div></div>';
            } ?>

            </div>
               
            <div class="listing_unit_price_wrapper">
                <span class="price_label price_label_before" style="text-decoration: line-through;">De: R$ <?php meta('valordeoff');?></span><br> 
                <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">Por: R$ <?php meta('valoroff');?> </span>
                <span class="price_label"></span>
            </div>  
            </div>             
        </div>
    <?php  endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can limit how many pages appear with `posts_per_page`, but i don't have any pagination configured *(example: Navigation through pages, next page, older page...)*

So, i see two ways to solve it, but in both i need your guide.

**First:** There is a way to solve it without navigation functions configured.
**Second:** The only way to solve it is to configure the navigation on my page wordpress template.

I'm really stuck here. Waiting for your help, thanks!

Comment: You tested it (worked?errors)? About few month ago i made something exactly like yours and everything was ok. I used Paul Irish infinity scroll and implemented it via ajax into wordpress and everything was fine. Are you using ajax as well? **edit** just saw your image and find out your are using YITH plugin

Comment: The point is that i don't know how to make it work with Paul Irish (i tried already). Can you give me a path so i can try it?

Comment: This is one from thousand articles about implementing infinity scroll via ajax and Paul irish js code. [How to create infinity scroll](https://www.webhostingsecretrevealed.net/blog/wordpress-blog/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrolling-wp-site/)

Comment: But lets wait, maybe some one come to help you out about YITH plugin

Comment: But that's the question colin: I didn't have managed to configure pagination on my page template. Reading the Paul Irish tutorial, i'll need some pagination configured. Tomorrow i'll read how to create a pagination navigation on wordpress, so i can configure the infinite scroll sucessfully. That was the help i was hoping for... Do you have something do add? Some tip, once you made that path before?

Comment: When you made your theme a pagination, grab `page` and `max_num_pages` (both are part of wordpress core) and set them in a `a` tag by `data-` and then fetch them via ajax and do the magic

Comment: I'm kinda new to ajax, but i think i understood what you're saying. Thanks, friend!